# Why $_SERVER REMOTE_ADDR returns blank?

Tags: php, cron, localhost

I have a php script log.php, it will record client **$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']** value to a text file.

I use cron-job to trigger this script, but all the recorded remote_addr values are blank instead of 127.0.0.1.

Why it return blank?

Comment: How are you triggering the script? I mean, calling wget, curl or just php on the command line?

Comment: `$_SERVER` is not a function, it's an array. Array elements are accessed using `[]`, not `()`.

Comment: If you're running PHP from the CLI, there's no `REMOTE_ADDR`, since there's no network client.

Comment: this is my command on cron-job, **/usr/bin/php -q /home/u011395/dev_folder/log.php**

Comment: Barmar: oh sorry that is a typo.

Comment: How will it record a client IP from a cron job?! What's the "client" there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mr. Barmar wrote in comments, `$_SERVER` variables (as well as some other PHP features) work only when executing script via application server (e.g. Apache). If you execute it via your terminal/console/whatever, there is actually no "client", so no "client"-linked information too.